# Html table column issue

Tags: html, css

This html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
 <body style="width:100%;">
  <table style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>fizz</td>
    <td>buzz</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Draws:

[image]

**Problem** is that I need something like this:

[image]

- First two columns should "stick" together
- Second column should expand and use unused space
- 3rd and 4th column should "stick" together like first two does

Any suggestions how to make this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table style='width:100%'>
    <col width="1" />
    <col>
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>fizz</td>
        <td>buzz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this will  make first, third and 4th as small possible, while second column takes the rest of the width.

Comment: If 4th column will have something like "buzz buzz buzz buzz", cell will be broken into 4 lines despite that 2nd column doesn't actually use space. Can fix that with `style="white-space:nowrap` though. Looks like this might be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width on "foo", "fizz", and "buzz". Give "bar" 100% width.

**EDIT:**

```
<table style='width:100%'>
    <col>
    <col width="100%" />
    <col>
    <col>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>fizz</td>
        <td>buzz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This should give the second column 100% width and allow the contents in the other columns to expand as well. I've tested this in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 9.

Comment: I don't know exact widths for 1,3,4 cols. For 1,3 I might fine tune it, but not 4th for sure.

Comment: I see Dan had a similar thought. +1 to him.

Answer (score 0):

Give them % width (in tagname or CSS)

> ***body must be 100 % width too***

exemple tagname:

html file:

```
<td width="10%"></td>
```

---

exemple css:

html file:

```
<td id="foo"></td>
```

css file :

```
#foo  { width: 10%; }
```

---

Or use javascript if you want to calculate width in pixel. (I recommande jQuery for compatibility)

[jQuery .innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)

Comment: I know how to set width. Either in html directly or css or js. That's not the problem. Problem is that I don't know exact width and how to "stick" 1st with 2nd and 3rd with 4th columns together while filling rest of the space with 2nd column.

Comment: You can calculate it with javascript, calculate innerwidth of the browser, than set fixed width to each columns then when you add together columns that you know width and you remove this from the innerwidth you have the exact width that you can put on the 2nd column

For exemple you have 950px of innerwidth, column 1 = 10px, column 3 = 20px, column 4 = 30px, so you have 60px of column that you know, 950 - 60 = 890px for the second columns.

Every client have different innerwidth, that's why it's better to work with jQuery.innerWidth()

Answer (score 0):

Or fixed widths for foo, bar, fizz and buzz columns and inject another column in the middle as third - it should automatically span over the available space.

Comment: If I will put fixed width for 2nd column too small, cells will break into 2 lines too fast. If I will put it too large - 3rd or 4th column will break despite that 2nd column doesn't actually use space.